# Satellites GOES16 and 17 - reprojection to Mercator is stretched

Tags: mercator, goes-16

I have downloaded GEOS data from https://cdn.star.nesdis.noaa.gov/GOES16/ABI/FD/ (or https://cdn.star.nesdis.noaa.gov/GOES17/ABI/FD/). I want to reproject the disk to Mercator projection. I have used equations from https://www.cgms-info.org/documents/cgms-lrit-hrit-global-specification-(v2-8-of-30-oct-2013).pdf (section 4.4). However, resulting image is stretched.

I have set for GOES16:

```
"lon": -75.0,
"COFF": 5424.5,
"LOFF": 5424.5,
"CFAC": 623.331875855,
"LFAC": -623.331875855
```

The same data with borderd rendered. My border is red, yellow one is from GEOS data image.

Callifornia is off a bit:

[image]

However, Cuba, Haiti etc. is ok

[image]

The reprojection is correct near the center longitude and the more to the edge, the more incorrect it is.

Any ideas why? I dont have this problem with Himawari and Eumetsat using same equations (borderd are perfect fit), so I think my implementation of them is correct.

Comment: Did you look at: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/345650/how-do-i-add-projection-to-this-netcdf-file-satellite

Comment: @snowman2 Yes, but I dont have netCDF file, only the images that should be in GEOS projection