# Transforms from the same file are different

Tags: rasterio, netcdf, rioxarray, xarray

Reading a NetCDF file in two ways:

1. `src = rasterio.open(f'NetCDF:{url}:Rad', 'r')` and doing `src.transform` gives:

   `Affine(2004.017315487541, 0.0, -5434894.700982174, 0.0, -2004.017315487541,  5434894.700982174)`

Whereas reading the same file as

2. `ncfile = xarray.open_dataset(str(url), engine='netcdf4', decode_coords="all")`
   and doing `ncfile['Rad'].rio.transform()` gives:

   `Affine(5.599999810285109e-05, 0.0, -0.15187199485493216, 0.0, -5.599999810285109e-05, 0.15187199485493216)`

Why is it so?

Comment: Did you try rioxarray.open_rasterio?

Comment: Are you able to provide the file?

Comment: `rio.open_rasterio(f'NetCDF:{url}:Rad', 'r').rio.transform()` gives the same as 1

Comment: @snowman2 here you go https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MLJKvrcTaxbfJ7gRd-H4kUibOIdlYtAk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add projection to this NetCDF file? (Satellite)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/345650/how-do-i-add-projection-to-this-netcdf-file-satellite)

Comment: I looked at the file, and it seems to be a GOES 16 netCDF file similar to the one mentioned above. I think GDAL handles some conversions automatically for you.

Comment: but I am using rasterio, xarray and rioxarray

Comment: I don't think it answers the question.

Comment: rioxarray uses rasterio, and rasterio is a python wrapper for GDAL.

Comment: So why two different values then?

Comment: I believe the netCDF driver in GDAL handles the conversion in the issue above for you.