# Using Rioxarray / QGIS Projection

Tags: qgis, rasterio, pyproj, xarray, rioxarray

For the past couple weeks I have been trying to view GOES17 data from netCDF files (converted to geotif) in QGIS 3.10 but cannot get the projection to work correctly.

I have attempted numerous methods but most recently tried the procedure of the top answer in this post:
[Converting NetCDF dataset array to GeoTiff using rasterio Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/323317/converting-netcdf-dataset-array-to-geotiff-using-rasterio-python/329141#329141)

When loading the .tif into QGIS, it appears in the wrong place relative the OpenStreetMap. I have tried several projections including EPSG:3857, which is what appears in the bottom right in QGIS when the OSM is loaded. They are all wrong.

I have also tried this answer:
[How do I add projection to this NetCDF file? (Satellite)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/345650/how-do-i-add-projection-to-this-netcdf-file-satellite)

When attempting the reproject function I get an error.

```py
xds3857 = xds.rio.reproject("epsg:3857")
```

Error:

```
DimensionError: x dimension not found. 'set_spatial_dims()' can address this.
```

xds:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:                                 (number_of_LZA_bounds: 2, number_of_SZA_bounds: 2, number_of_image_bounds: 2, number_of_time_bounds: 2, x: 1086, y: 1086)
Coordinates:
    t                                       datetime64[ns] 2020-02-03T19:05:05.476645888
  * y                                       (y) float32 0.1519 ... -0.15190002
  * x                                       (x) float32 -0.1519 ... 0.15190002
    goes_imager_projection                  int32 -2147483647
    y_image                                 float32 0.0
    x_image                                 float32 0.0
    retrieval_local_zenith_angle            float32 85.0
    quantitative_local_zenith_angle         float32 70.0
    solar_zenith_angle                      float32 180.0
    time                                    int32 -2147483647
    spatial_ref                             int64 0
```

The issue continues to persist after doing the suggestion.

```py
xds.rio.set_spatial_dims("x","y",inplace=True)
```

Comment: Can you post a link to the input file?

Comment: Here is the aws command:
```aws s3 cp s3://noaa-goes17/ABI-L2-LSTF/2020/034/19/OR_ABI-L2-LSTF-M6_G17_s20200341900321_e20200341909388_c20200341910038.nc ./ --no-sign-request;```

Comment: Looks like the first step is to convert it to geodetic lat/lon. https://makersportal.com/blog/2018/11/25/goes-r-satellite-latitude-and-longitude-grid-projection-algorithm

Comment: This also looks promising: http://meteothink.org/examples/meteoinfolab/satellite/geos-16.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Upon inspecting the dataset, I realized that the units of the data are in radians.

```py
import xarray
import rioxarray
from pyproj import CRS

xds = xarray.open_dataset("OR_ABI-L2-LSTF-M6_G17_s20200341900321_e20200341909388_c20200341910038.nc")
```

Inside the `x` variable the attributes say the data is in radians:

```
xds.x.attrs
```

```
{'units': 'rad',
 'axis': 'X',
 'long_name': 'GOES Projection x-Coordinate',
 'standard_name': 'projection_x_coordinate'}
```

According to this post http://meteothink.org/examples/meteoinfolab/satellite/geos-16.html, you just need to multiply by the `perspective_point_height` to convert to meters.

```py
sat_height = xds.goes_imager_projection.attrs["perspective_point_height"]
xds.x.values *= sat_height
xds.y.values *= sat_height
```

Next, set the CRS of the dataset:

```py
cc = CRS.from_cf(xds.goes_imager_projection.attrs)
xds.rio.write_crs(cc.to_string(), inplace=True)
```

Also, there are only two variables with the `x` and `y` dimensions:

```
Data variables:
    LST                                     (y, x) float32 ...
    DQF                                     (y, x) float32 ...
```

As such, only those ones will work, so you need to pull those out:

```py
xds = xds[["LST", "DQF"]]
```

Then, you can reproject and export to raster:

```py
xds3857 = xds.rio.reproject("EPSG:3857")
xds3857.rio.to_raster("geos17.tif")
```

It seemed to work:

[image]

Comment: I am getting this error at the reprojection line:
```CRSError: The WKT could not be parsed. OGR Error code 5```.

I have GDAL 2.2.3, rasterio 1.1.2, and rioxarray 0.0.21. Also, not sure if it is relevant but I have to import rioxarray after opening the dataset, otherwise I get ```OSError: [Errno -101] NetCDF: HDF error:```

Comment: Looks like you are using a version of GDAL that does not support WKT2. I updated the script so that it should work now.

Comment: What method did you use for installation?

Comment: rioxarray, xarray, and rasterio were through pip. Not sure, but I think GDAL was through apt. Thanks for all the help and for making rioxarray!

Comment: @snowman2 , what is CRS ?‌ How should I import it?

Comment: from pyproj import CRS