# Figuring out CRS projection of .nc file

Tags: python, coordinate-system

I have 3 `.nc` files that were given to me without specifying which projection was used for the (lat, lon) coordinate pairs. Is there an attribute or a way of figuring it out given the latitudes and longitudes that are written in the file?

It's especially important to me to know since I need to obtain the closest grid points to a list of locations that are in `epsg:4326` and compare the data stored in each.

I am using Python3 and GeoPandas to store the geographical information and plot.

I am new working with `.nc`and geographical data but it is my understanding different `crs` might change the `(lat, lon)` pair, so they cant be compared if they are not projected onto the same coordinate system.

Comment: Are you able to share the netcdf file? It can vary depending on how it was created.

Comment: They were created with the `chimere` software, haven't been able to figure out if `chimere` uses a specific `crs` or if its given by the user. Don't feel comfortable sharing it since it's from my superior and not mine.

Comment: If it can't be figured out without sharing the `.nc` I will understand and will delete the question

Comment: This may help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/350006/144357. But you might have something different, so hard to tell without the file.